# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/ByteType in Spring Boot 3 with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am developing a Spring Boot application that uses Hibernate for data persistence. While trying to execute a specific query using Hibernate's fetchCount() method, I encountered the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/ByteType
```

Here's the code snippet where the error is occurring:

```
// This is the line that causes the error
long total = query.fetchCount();
```

I suspect there might be some version mismatch that I'm overlooking.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20220924</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
        <version>0.11.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.3</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>
                        -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true
                    </arg>
                    <arg>
                        -Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true
                    </arg>
                    <arg>
                        -Amapstruct.verbose=true
                    </arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is my stack trace :

```
    Processing method: getAllFiltered
2023-07-04T15:19:39,125 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.a.LoggingAspect:83: *****************************************************************************
2023-07-04T15:19:39,126 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.a.LoggingAspect:107: ip 172.25.20.171 Enter: getAllFiltered() with argument[s] = [null,null,null,null,1,10] and files = []
2023-07-04T15:19:39,298 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.a.LoggingAspect:121: *****************************************************************************
2023-07-04T15:19:39,300 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.e.ControllerAdvice:40: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
2023-07-04T15:19:39,300 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.e.ControllerAdvice:41: Unhandled Exception name: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/ByteType
2023-07-04T15:19:39,300 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.e.ControllerAdvice:42: Unhandled Exception message: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/type/ByteType
2023-07-04T15:19:39,300 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.e.ControllerAdvice:44: Printing Exception stack: 
2023-07-04T15:19:39,301 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10] m.n.t.e.ControllerAdvice:49: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1096)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
```

org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)

Can someone please help me identify the cause of this error and suggest a solution to resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show your pom.xml or your build.gradle file?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I just updated my question.

Comment: Why do you override the versions of spring-data-jpa and javax.persistence-api? You should use the tested configuration from spring Boot

Comment: Thanks I used the tested configuration from spring Boot. I still have the same problem

Comment: Are you using ByteType in the code?

Comment: And which querydsl version are you using?

Comment: I'm using querydsl version 5.0.0. and I'm not using the ByteType, This is the line that causes the error ' long total = query.fetchCount(); '

Comment: can you please proivde the whole stack trace

Comment: That's not the whole stacktrace

Comment: Remove the `spring-data-jpa` dependency, remove the `persistence-api` dependency. Spring Boot 3 is for JakartaEE not JavaEE and the Spring Data JPA version you included is old as well. All the needed dependencies are already pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.